# Store the state of a variable in C#

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I am working on a c# application that is serially encrypted when user install the application and runs application first time I ask user for key and if he enters right key. I run the application. But my requirement that this process should be one time after installation only,
I think there are two possibilities.

1. Store software validation state in a variable and use it to allow the running of application (I do not want to use XML,Object serialize as I have to save the state of one variable also user can remove files created by serialize).
2. Ask user about key while he is installing application,If he enter wrong key then he should not be able to install the software.

Can some body answer

1. Is there a simple way to store the state of a single variable.

Or
 2. How to trigger installer manually (after validation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for something like this, i would encrypt it and store it in the registry.  this is not they type of thing that you want to store in a settings file.  you can check out [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/modifyregistry.aspx) codeproject article on how to access the registry using C#.

Answer (score 5):

[Software Protection](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=software%20protection) is an old and expansive topic. The current state of the art, is that it's not really possible to protect you software 100% reliable. Sooner or later, someone will crack it anyway, given enough exposure and/or interest.

Nonetheless, a lot of people and companies protect their software products and there are a number of way to this (not 100% reliably however).

It is not clear what your requirements are, from your question. Given what you've described, the simplest option would be to zip up the installer with a password. If a user don't know the correct password they won't be able to unpack the zip file and install your program.

This is usually not very practical, as the same password is provided for everyone. You want to do your own serial key validation, and you considering doing this at installation time. If this is the route you want to go for you will need to provide some script that will do validation to your installation system. You indicated, that you are using windows installer. You can user [Windows Installer XML (WiX) toolset](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) to author an installation. Given enough patience, you can built the key validation into your windows installer package. Most practical way possible is to call your validation routine that you've writen in c# from the wix package. You can use [Conditional Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012%28VS.85%29.aspx) to check conditions in your installation. This should cover your option 2.

As for option 1, then whenever in the system you store your piece of information, user always will be able to get there and change it (it's their computer after all). Some people store this in registry, some in key files. Deleting these files is usually not a problem, because if user deletes them, your program will know that it should not run. However a user would be able to copy them on other machine, etc.

[Isolated Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx) is yet another place to store you information with .NET. Ultimately it is some deeply buried files in the file system anyway.

Once again, Software Protection is a complex topic, it's up to you to decide, what you requirements are, what compromises you can afford and what you choose to implement.

Good luck!